# Как выполнить команду для отключения компьютера в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlineedit, qtimer

Я создал простенькую программу с интерфейсом на *PyQt5*, чисто для практики, которая должна выключать компьютер через определённое время.

У меня есть поле `lineEdit` для ввода времени в секундах. 
И у меня возник такой вопрос, как сделать, чтобы выполнить команду, которая выполнит отключение компьютера.

Я новичок и пока что просто практикуюсь. Помогите пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `os.system(command)` - исполняет системную команду, возвращает код её завершения (в случае успеха 0). https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-system-method/

Comment: Не могли бы вы подробнее объяснить? вот код который нужно вывести в cmd: def print_lineEdit(self):
        text = self.lineEdit.text()  # значение из поля LineEdit
        print(f'Shutdown /s /t  {text}')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс `QTimer` предоставляет **`повторяющиеся`** и **`однократные`** таймеры. 
Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html

> void QTimer::**singleShot**(int msec, const QObject *receiver, const char *member)
>
> Эта статическая функция вызывает слот по истечении заданного интервала времени.

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from Shutdown import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(390, 154)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(17, 23, 18);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 110, 75, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
        "border-radius: 30;")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 211, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(92, 110, 148);")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 50, 113, 41))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(5, 9, 18);\n"
        "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
        "font: 75 12pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.lineEdit.setText("")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setStyleSheet("")
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ОК"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите время (в секундах):"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        # тут ваша  логика
        
        validador = QtCore.QRegExp("[0-9]*")
        ok = QtGui.QRegExpValidator(validador, self)
        self.lineEdit.setValidator(ok)
        self.lineEdit.setFocus()
        
        self.pushButton.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(75, 23))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        
        self.lcd = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber()
        self.lcd.setSegmentStyle(QtWidgets.QLCDNumber.Filled)
        self.lcd.setDigitCount(8)
        self.lcd.display('')
        
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lcd, 0, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 1, 0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 2, 0, 1, 2, 
                                  alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateTime)
        self.sec = 0

    def updateTime(self):
        self.lcd.display(self.sec)
        self.sec -= 1
        
    def on_clicked(self):
        self.text = self.lineEdit.text()
        if not self.text: return
        
        self.sec = int(self.text)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(self.sec*1000+1 , self.cmd)
        self.timer.start(1000)
        self.lineEdit.clear()

    def cmd(self):
        print(f'Прошло {self.text} секунд - делайте что-нибудь.') 
        self.timer.stop()
        self.lcd.display('')
        
        # os.system('shutdown -s')                       # <----  
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Для запуска внешней команды из Python можно использовать одну из следующих опций:

1. **os.system** - см. описание https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-os-python/funktsija-system-modulja-os/
2. **subprocess** - см. https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-subprocess-python/

Например, если у вас на компьютере установлена ОС Windows, выключить компьютер через 180 секунд можно вот таким кусочком Python-кода:

```
import os

os.system("shutdown /s /t 180")
```

Здесь вызывается внешняя команда shutdown, которая и делает основную работу. Python здесь выступает в роли обёртки.

Comment: А как мне сделать так,что бы os.system выводила функцию в cmd?Так как у меня программа с интерфейсом,в lineEdit вводится числовое значение которое сохраняется в переменную text, вот как это выглядит: def print_lineEdit(self):
        text = self.lineEdit.text()  # значение из поля LineEdit
        print(f"Shutdown /s /t  {text}")